# How to enable nginx proxy pass?

Tags: http, web, nginx, proxy, webserver

I have an inner server that runs my application. This application runs on port `9001`. I want people access this application through `nginx` which runs on an `Ubuntu` machine that runs on `DMZ` network.

I have built `nginx` from source with the options of `sticky` and `SSL` modules. It runs fine but does not do the proxy pass.

The `DNS` name for the outer IP of the server is: `bd.com.tr` and I want people to see the page `http://bd.com.tr/public/control.xhtml` when they enter `bd.com.tr` but even tough nginx redirects the root request to my desired path, the application does not show up.

My nginx.conf file is:

```
worker_processes  4;
error_log  logs/error.log;

worker_rlimit_nofile 20480;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1900;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_tokens off;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    keepalive_timeout  75;

    rewrite_log on;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Ssl on;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_read_timeout      150;

    server  {

        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 300M;

        location = / {
                rewrite ^ http://bd.com.tr/public/control.xhtml redirect;
         }

         location /public {
           proxy_pass http://BACKEND_IP:9001;
        }
    }

}
```

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly problem and I found it. The `conf` file is correct so you can use it if you want and the problem was; The port `9001` of the `BACKEND_IP` was not forwarded and thus `nginx` was not able to reach the inner service. After forwarding the port, it worked fine. I found the problem in `error.log` so if you encounter such problem please check error logs first :)